# How return html page in Spring Boot without thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf, get-mapping

If i delete from pom.xml spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf then my @GetMapping cant return html page.
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHTcD.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJvOn.png)

I tried:

1. add @ResponseBody - not working (his return string in web site, not html page)
2. Replace @Controller by @RestControllerin - not working
3. Using ModelAndView - not working (modelAndView.setViewName("index" or "index.html" or "static/index.html" or ...)

Answer (score 1):

> 1. add @ResponseBody - not working (his return string in web site, not
>    html page)

Because the browser will read your response header "Content-Type" to decide how to show the content. So that you need to specify the content type to html.

```
@GetMapping("/")
public void indexPage(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=utf-8"); //specify the content is html
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.write("<form action='#' method='post'>");
    out.write("username：");
    out.write("<input type='text' name='username'><br/>");
    out.write("password：");
    out.write("<input type='password' name='password'><br/>");
    out.write("<input type='submit' value='login'>");
    out.write("</form>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to response HTML page without Thymeleaf

```
@GetMapping("/home")
public String loadHomePage() {
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("templates/html/home.html");
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
        byte[] byteData = FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(inputStream);
        String content = new String(byteData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        LOGGER.info(content);
        return content;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("IOException", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```